# Error on countNonZero when used to compare two Mats

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, assertion, mat

I took screenshots of each slide of the powerpoint and stored them into an `ArrayList` of Mats, I am trying to see when I reach the end of the slide show so I use a compare function. However, the implementation gives an exception on the `countNonZero` function:

> E/cv::error(): OpenCV(3.4.5) Error: Assertion failed (cn == 1) in int
>   cv::countNonZero(cv::InputArray), file
>   /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/count_non_zero.cpp,
>   line 298 E/org.opencv.core: core::countNonZero_10() caught
>   cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.5)
>   /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/count_non_zero.cpp:298:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) cn == 1 in function 'int
>   cv::countNonZero(cv::InputArray)' D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.autoslide, PID: 27129
>       CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.5)
>   /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/count_non_zero.cpp:298:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) cn == 1 in function 'int
>   cv::countNonZero(cv::InputArray)'
>       ]

**Here is the code:**

```
private void getScreens(WebView view) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            Bitmap b = Screenshot.takeScreenshot(view);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            Mat mat = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), mat);
            screens.add(mat);
            view.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT));
            i++;
            //System.out.println(screens.size());
        } while(i <= 4 || !(matEquals(screens.get(i-1), screens.get(i-2))));



    }

    public static boolean matEquals(Mat img1, Mat img2){
        Mat out = new Mat();
        Core.compare(img1, img2, out, Core.CMP_NE);
        return Core.countNonZero(out) == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure   the output here  `Core.compare(img1, img2, out, Core.CMP_NE);`  is a single channel `Mat`

check documentation [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#int%20countNonZero(InputArray%20src))